# Merge specific row in whole table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a web app, considering how to merge specific row in whole table.

Here is the example

Original data:

```
Name     Date
-------------------
Jason    Jul 2017
Tom      Jun 2018
Andy     Jun 2018
Mary     Jun 2018
Alex     Feb 2018
David    Aug 2018
```

I'd like to make the same result into one big cell,like what we can do in Excel

```
Name     Date
------------------
Jason    Jul 2017
Tom   
Andy     Jun 2018
Mary  
Alex     Feb 2018
David    Aug 2018
```

Is this possible in SQL Server? Or I need to do this change in the java or css layer

Comment: SQL tables have rows and columns.  All rows have the same set of columns.  Your result is not a table in this sense.  Hence, you cannot do exactly what you want in SQL.

Comment: you need to do this in your front end application where the result is display. Not in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

The exact output you want is something which is better handled in your presentation layer, e.g. using something like PHP, Java, etc.  Perhaps the closest we might get to your output in SQL Server would be to do a group concatenation of the names by date, something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.Date,
    STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + t2.Name
          FROM yourTable t2
          WHERE t1.Date = t2.Date
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS Names
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM yourTable) t1;
```

[image]

### Demo